# VIM hjkl navigation keys, aganist existing muscle memory of arrow keys

Tags: vim, keyboard, key-bindings

I recently migrated to Vim.
But I am having diffuculty making use of "hjkl" keys for navigating because of my existing **muscle memory of arrow keys**.

**1.** Is there a way to effectively use other keys like "**ijkl**" ( near
    to Arrow key layout ) without    causing much conflict to other
    functionality in VIM 
    ,   For ex: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_ijkl_to_move_the_cursor_and_h_to_insert
  and http://ergoemacs.org/misc/on_vi_keybinding.html

**2.**  Is it worth the efforts to retrain the muscle memory with "hjkl" ?     But the problem is, I have to use arrow keys again with
    **Web-Browser, Outlook**, and word processors ( So,the shift is causing the conflict) .

Can you suggest ( More interested to know about #2) , How did you deal with this ?

Comment: Get used to it, seriously. It took me some too time but nowadays, I don't really think about it. Remapping to **ijkl** is possible but not advisable. Every tutorial you'll follow or help you read will for example use `3j` to navigate or select 3 lines. You will always have to adjust your thinking to `3k`. That's counterproductive in the long run.

Comment: But, How do you align to the shift, when you are using Web browser, Word processors, emails ?

Comment: Most of the time without problems but I must admit that sometimes I have to remind myself about wether or not I'm working in Vim.

Answer (score 6):

I have been using Vim for five years (after many more years of computer usage) without *ever* doing any conscious or unconscious effort to use `HJKL` for navigation.

- I don't touch-type so the "home row" means nothing to me.
- Even if I did, `jkl;` would make a lot more sense anyway.
- I hit the arrows with the side of my right hand so there's not much cost in "reaching for the arrows" for me.
- `hjkl` are just as bad as the arrows because both only move character-by-character and line-by-line unless you use modifiers (numbers for `hjkl` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> for the arrows). Vim has vastly better means of transportation than either `hjkl` or the arrows and that's what you should spend time learning:

  ```
  wW          jump to next word/WORD
  bB          jump to beginning of word/WORD
  eE          jump to end of word/WORD
  fx          jump to next x on the line
  tx          jump to character just before next x on the line
  Fx          jump to previous x on the line
  Tx          jump to character just before previous x on the line
  /foo<CR>    jump to next foo
  ?bar<CR>    jump to previous bar
  }           jump to next blank line
  ```

and so on… `:h navigation` will blow your mind.

So my answer is: don't bother forcing yourself to use `hjkl`, it's not worth the hassle.

Comment: What do you think about mapping to "ijkl" , http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_ijkl_to_move_the_cursor_and_h_to_insert

Comment: @coder000001 +1 for the above.  A lot of the "hjkl" hype is just personal preference.  If you feel they increase your productivity, then fine, go ahead and use them.  If the arrows feel more natural to you, then just use the arrows.  It's just a tiny detail.  What do you think wil happen if you don't follow _somebody else's_ rules of typing, the keyboard fairies will get angry and come after you? :)

Comment: @lcd047, Thanks for your inputs :) 
..  I meant what commands will it conflict ?

Comment: +1 for demonstrating the many "better means of transportation" in Vim. @coder000001 `i` is the insert key, so you will have to remap it. Might as well just remap it to `h`. And be careful with `I` which is "insert at beginning of line".

Comment: I learned to use vim with this game: https://vim-adventures.com

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea to train your hand for `hjkl`. You could try playing rogue for a while on a daily basis until it's comfortable. It comes pretty quick.

Arrows are awful for taking your hand so far out of position. Even `<Enter>` is too far. I usually get away with `Ctrl-J` instead (a comfortable `Ctrl` is really important too!).

Using custom overrides for `hjkl` will only "help" your vim, but not other vim-like tools. In vim, remapping `i` will cause other issues, like what to use instead of `i`/`I`, which are very common. And you might not want to take over `;` for this since right-pinky is prime real estate which I (and I think many others) map to the very frequent `:` (at the OS level so as not to ever be confused).

Learning `hjkl` will also help when you're in other places: You probably want to start using vi-mode in bash (or hopefully zsh). Gmail/mutt will be more natural. REPLs with readline support also support vi-mode. Maybe you'll do less word processing if you can replace it with text editing in vim.

Sometimes it's useful to remap things, but it's rare and often to more obscure keys/sequences. It can cause problems when you work in multiple environments, and can make sharing/pairing difficult. It can break macros and other mappings, and make recipes and articles harder to interpret. Try learning the vim-native ways first, and then deviate with experience when really justified.

Comment: "so far out of position" I think this is less true on modern keyboards, especially on laptops. I'd rather keep my fingers on `jkl;` and just hit the arrow keys with my pinky.